# SharePoint List Add New Button Does Not Open "New Item Form"

Tags: sharepoint-online

I was trying to edit the New Item Form in SharePoint and something went wrong (i.e. I made a mistake). Now, when I click the New Item button, the form no longer opens. When I open the list in Infopath Designer (which I only just learned about while trying to fix this) I can see the form, so it's not lost. It's just that the link is broken. We are using the 365 Cloud version of SharePoint. Any ideas on how to fix this f_up? THANKS FOR ANY HELP YOU CAN GIVE!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Do other browsers have this problem?
- Try switching the page to the default SharePoint form in the Form Settings.Then clear your browser cache and refresh the page to see if that works.
  [image: form settings]
- You can create a new list view that looks exactly like this one, set it as the default, and see if the new view has this problem.

Comment: The default SharePoint Form option works. Should I delete the existing customized form and recreate it?

Comment: I went ahead and deleted the custom form and re-created it. All working fine now.